# Is there a threshold for seed generation?

Tags: nonce, revelation

by reading the doc we see that there are 128 nonces per cycle, and all revealed nonces are used to generate the seed. Any baker who fails to reveal their nonce forfeits all rewards for the respective cycle (not bonds, just rewards)

But what if **there is only 100 nonces revealed** is it enough to generate the seed ? what is the threshold to generate the seed 50 , 100 , 128 ? **What happen if we don't have enough nonce** revealed to generate the seed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the number of nonces revealed, but the number of bakers revealing. If only one baker reveals one or more nonces, he could try to compute the nonce so that he will receive more baking/endorsing slots in the future. The more different are the bakers who reveal, the less likely they can cooperate to do that...

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs:](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/docs/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.rst)

> The seed of cycle `(n-PRESERVED_CYCLES-2)` is hashed with a constant
>   and then with each revelation of cycle `(n-PRESERVED_CYCLES-1)`.
>   Once computed, this new seed is stored and used during cycle `n`.

Based on this, there is no min threshold of revelations required.